# Issue in Edittext Background opacity in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have two edittext in which i set opacity for that below is my images.

[image]

Below is my Layout Code

**main.xml**

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.23"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
         android:background="@drawable/backwithborder"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
       >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.23"
        android:ems="10"
        android:background="@drawable/backwithborder"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
         />
```

**backwithborder.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dip"
    android:color="#ffffff" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    mEditTextU.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1)
        {
              mEditTextU.setAlpha(100.0f);
            return false;
        }
    });
    mEditTextP.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1)
        {

              mEditTextP.setAlpha(100.0f);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**when i run above code and focus in email edittext it opacity set like below image**

[image]

**but i want like this**

[image]

so any idea how can i solve it ?

Comment: remove `padding=10dp`

Comment: You can accept my answer if you get it useful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have problem with `android:padding="10dp"` that you have defined in both `EditText`, Try to remove it.

Reduced Code Like:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.23"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:background="@drawable/backwithborder"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black" />

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.23"
        android:ems="10"
        android:background="@drawable/backwithborder"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The code `android:padding="10dp"` actually applies to your edittext and focuses it like you have mentioned.